# Why won't my query run properly? When ever I pass a string variable through the executeQuery method I get an error

Tags: java, sql, sum

There is an error on the line that says ps = stmt.executeQuery();....the     error says method executeQuery in interface Statement cannot be applied to given types;
    required: String
    found: no arguments
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

But whenever I pass a String through that line I get an error saying java.sql.SQLException:Method 'executeQuery(String)' not allowed on prepared statement...

This method is for a button that adds all the Integer values in a column of SQL table.

```
private void btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

try{

String SQL = "SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM MENU";

stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL);

ps = stmt.executeQuery();

if(ps.next()) {

String total = ps.getString("SUM(PRICE)");

textTotalCost.setText(total);
      }                    
    }

catch (SQLException err) {

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err);
    } 

 }
```

Comment: In which line are you getting error ? The question is framed poorly.
Did you try changing that `MQL` to `SQL`. ?

Comment: I'm getting an error in the line that says ps = stmt.executeQuery(MQL);. Also when I changed MQL to SQL I still got an error.

Comment: Please provide more information about the error.

Comment: When I pass a string variable through the executeQuery method and I run the program and I click on the button that this method corresponds to I get an error saying Method 'executeQuery(String)' not allowed on prepared statement

Comment: When I don't pass a string variable through the executeQuery method and I run the program I get an error that says "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.sql.Statement.

Comment: @VishvakRangarajan -- instead of replying to comments, edit your original question to provide more context and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated following the question change*

There is no column name explicitly specified for the calculated column `SUM(PRICE)` in your SQL statement. It would hardly ever actually be "SUM(PRICE)". Try naming your column. Also `prepareStatement` is useful when passing parameters. Simple `Select` does not need it:

```
private void btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try{
         String SQL = "SELECT SUM(PRICE) As PRICE_TOTAL FROM MENU";
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet ps = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
         if(ps.next()) {
             String total = ps.getString("PRICE_TOTAL");
             textTotalCost.setText(total);
         }                    
    }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err);
    } 
}
```

or access the value by column index rather than name:

```
private void btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try{
         String SQL = "SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM MENU";
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet ps = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
         if(ps.next()) {
             String total = ps.getString(0);
             textTotalCost.setText(total);
         }                    
    }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err);
    } 
}
```

Comment: The line ps = stmt.executeQuery(MQL); should actually be ps = stmt.executeQuery(); That is where the error is occuring

Answer (score 0):

Column name is must while getting a data

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your description but I think you are trying to assign the PreparedStatement created in

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL)
```

to a variable of type Statement (stmt) and that's causing the error. The line of code above works because PreparedStatement is an extension (or implementation) of Statement but

```
ps = stmt.executeQuery();
```

fails because the class Statement doesn't have an executeQuery method without parameters, PreparedStatement does.
[@Y.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5690722/y-b)'s solution and the rest of recommendations are good (the alias for sum(price) or getting the value by column index) if it's ok using a regular Statement. The alternative is changing the type of stmt to PreparedStatement in your original code.